# Subquery in laravel query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How could I do this query in laravel:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT * FROM `tb_horario` where cod_funcionario="'.$cod.'" and deleted_at is null)
AS temp
where temp.motivo!='' or temp.validado=0
```

but sometimes I dont have to use cod_funcionario because is a filter in my page

so I've something like:

```
if ($funcionario)
        {               
            $horariosQuery->where('cod_funcionario', $funcionario);
        }
```

I dont know how to do this query with this subquery in laravel like I did in sql.
thxx!

Comment: Did you find this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815551/how-to-do-this-in-laravel-subquery-where-in

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to do something like, but I'm not sure where I put that filter, in whereIn before the subquery or inside the subquery

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you need a subquery here. Why can't you `AND temp.motivo!='' or temp.validado=0`?

Comment: because if I dont filter "cod_funcionario" I select extra data, because it can be or "validado" or "motivo!=''" and if I dont select "funcionario" before I get data from other employee because of the OR

Comment: Then what you need to read is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-where-with-or-and-or

Comment: thx man that helped i could solve

Answer (score 1):

```
 $horariosQuery = $this->horario->with(array('funcionario', 'item_contabil'))
                              ->whereNull('deleted_at')
                              ->orderby('cod', 'ASC');

        if ($funcionario)
        {               
            $horariosQuery->where('cod_funcionario', $funcionario)
                          ->where(function ($query) {
                                $query->where('validado', 0)
                                      ->orWhere('motivo', '!=', '');
                            })
                          ->orderBy('data');
        }
        else
        {
            $horariosQuery->where('validado', 0)
                          ->orWhere('motivo', '<>', '')
                          ->orderBy('cod_funcionario');
        }
```