# Eloquent: Or clause in where statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is the following query possible with Eloquent ORM without using `whereRaw()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE name="John"
OR name="Bill";
```

This is the exact problem that I have.  I need to find a certain set of specific values from a certain column that is NOT the primary key (and so I cannot use `find()`).

However, I would be interested in the more general `OR` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE name="John"
OR age="26";
```

in which you can put any number `OR` clauses together, regardless of their content.

As I understand it, chaining multiple `->where()`s will connect them using `AND`. I.e.:

```
User::where("name", "=", "John")
  -> where("name", "=", "Bill)
  -> get();
```

produces

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE name="John"
AND name="Bill";
```

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 eloquent WHERE with OR AND OR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-where-with-or-and-or)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is *orWhere*. From [the Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queries)

```
$users = DB::table('users')
             ->where('votes', '>', 100)
             ->orWhere('name', 'John')
             ->get();
```

Comment: is this really using Eloquent, though?  It's a perfectly fine solution, and probably what I will use, but it doesn't really seem in keeping with the nature of the ORM

Comment: @ewok Eloquent has both the where and orWhere methods. So the code above would work just as well if you replace DB::table('users') with User::where('name', '=', 'John')->orWhere('name', '=', 'Bill');