# How to add multiple where clause on Eloquent ORM Laravel?

Tags: php, oop, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

Having a hard time here trying to retrieve specific records where I need the ID and the Date to match, here is my code:

```
      $testq= DB::table('attendances')->where('user_id', '=', $userinput && 'logon', '=', $newdate)->get();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add one more where.

```
$testq= DB::table('attendances')
    ->where('user_id', '=', $userinput)
    ->where('logon', '=', $newdate)
    ->get();
```

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_where

> $this where(string $column, string $operator = null, mixed $value =
>   null, string $boolean = 'and')
>
> Add a basic where clause to the query.

Comment: excuse me for asking you one more, but can you tell me how to use if statement and determine if the record exist? 'if($testq exists)' ?

Comment: @jakebalba, you could check $testq->count() http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_count

Comment: so it will be like this ? 'if ($testq->count()<1)' sorry newbie here

Comment: @jakebalba, you have wrote the code - do not ask - test it. Test takes less time than asking : )

Comment: @jakebalba, add one more question with your code and attemps

Comment: Still have another problem sir, I think the code is just using 'OR' and not 'AND'

Comment: @jakebalba, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-where-with-or-and-or

Comment: How about when you want to retrieve all the values (and including `NULL`) except one. In My case I don't get the `NULL` rows. For example, `->where('country_id','!=',120)` But I don't get the `NULL` values. How do I fix this? -> I just found out by adding `->orWhereNull('country_id')` ;)

Answer (score 5):

As an addition to @sectus's answer, you might like this syntax:

```
$testq= DB::table('attendances')->whereUserId($userinput)
                                ->whereLogon($newdate)
                                ->get();
```