# Difference between whereOr and orWhere in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have used `whereOr` and `orWhere` in my code in **Laravel** both works but at times gives different result

```
$user_query = User::select( 'users.id', 'users.username','users.first_name','users.last_name', 'users.photo' )
                    ->where('users.status',1)
                    ->where('users.id','!=',$id)
                    ->where('users.username','like','%'.$searchkey.'%')
                    ->orWhere('users.first_name','like','%'.$searchkey.'%')
                    ->orwhere('users.last_name','like','%'.$searchkey.'%')->get();

                    // ->whereOr('users.first_name','like','%'.$searchkey.'%')
                    // ->whereOr('users.last_name','like','%'.$searchkey.'%')->get();
```

What's the difference between `whereOr` and `orWhere`

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-where-with-or-and-or

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 Where does that mention `whereOr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both *can* do the same. But not really, since you're using `whereOr` wrong. `whereOr` is a **dynamic** where. They are described a bit more in depth in [this blogpost](http://www.neontsunami.com/posts/dynamic-where-clauses-and-find-methods-in-eloquent-%28laravel-4%29)

With dynamic wheres, the condition is defined not only parameters but by the method name itself. Here's an example:

```
->whereAge(18);
```

it could be translated into

```
->where('age', '=', 18);
```

This is done with the `__call()` function which then calls [`dynamicWhere()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L941-L976). This method then decodes the method name you called and saved that info as a where condition.

Now with `whereOr` you would actually have to call it like:

```
->whereAgeOrGender(18, 'male');
```

This means it gives you an easy syntax but is much less flexible than "real" wheres. For example it will **always use the `=` operator**. So it's definitely not suitable for your case.