# Returns the records even year is not correct

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do some year filtering where only get those records base on the specified date, below is my complete eloquent query.

```
$products = product::whereYear('created_at', '2009')
            ->where('type_id','!=','')
            ->orWhereNotNull('type_id')
            ->with('type','product_warehouses.warehouse')
            ->get();
```

currently, i only have records within year 2017 but it still gives me the records even i specify the date to '2009'. However, if i take out this

```
->orWhereNotNull('type_id')
```

the query works like it gives me records base on the given year. Any ideas, help please?

Comment: the hint is in **or** `WhereNotNull` because now you have an OR condition. I guess you want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-where-with-or-and-or)

Comment: yeah, that's my thought too. fix now

Answer (score 0):

Fix, I can just use instead,

```
$products = product::whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))->where(function($query){
        $query->where('type_id','!=','');
        $query->orWhere('type_id','!=',null);
    })->with('type','product_warehouses.warehouse')->get();
```

or

```
->where('type_id','!=','')
->orWhere('type_id','!=',null)
```