# Laravel 5.6 selection by active records

Tags: php, laravel, mysqli, pdo, laravel-5.6

User table

depart_id              |  user_role

5                       | 1

4,2                    | 2

5,2                    | 2

1,5                    | 1

I want to fetch all user with user_role=1 and depart_id=5 and depart_id=1

How to achieve using active record(or usual query)?

My  code is

```
$user_depart = array(5,1);
$user_role   = 1;

$data = DB::table('tbl_users')
            ->where('user_role', $user_role)
            ->whereIn('department_id',$user_depart)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Do you mean depart_id=5 **or** depart_id=1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 eloquent WHERE with OR AND OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-where-with-or-and-or)

Comment: Why is there a `,` in the `depart_id` column? Is this a floating point number or multiple values?

Comment: @kabanus i want both 5 and 1

Comment: @Jerodev My table keeps different depart_id separate with commas

Comment: @OfficialONE You mean both objects with 5 and 1, or in another wording, all objects that have either 1 or 5?

Comment: @OfficialONE That is a very bad way to make a database and might bring forward problems in the future.

Comment: @kabanus required out put is 5 | 1 and 1,5|1

Comment: @Jerodev yes ofcourse, its a running project and am not permission to edit the schema. I know its ulgly db design...

Answer (score 0):

You have created an  bad database structure. Best way - create table users_departs (user_id, depart_id)

And then you can do like this:

```
$userDeparts = [5,1];
$userRole = 1;
$users = User::with('users.departs')
    ->where('users.role_id', $userRole)
    ->whereIn('departs.id', $userDeparts)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think a simple whereIn will work here. Given the schema of your table it is not quite a good practice assigning multiple keys in your column (IMO) 
but you could give a try this. I tried using `LIKE` statement.

```
$user_depart = array(5,1);
$user_role   = 1;

$data = DB::table('tbl_users')
        ->where('user_role', $user_role)
        ->where(function($sql) use ($user_depart){
             for($i = 0; $i < count($user_depart); $i++){
                  $sql->orWhere('department_id','LIKE','%' . $user_depart[$i] . '%');
             }
        })
        ->get();
```