# Laravel where and whereOr

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am having some trouble with `where`/`whereOr` queries. I want to check if `fitting` and `dimmability` are the same. Then the `light_color_code` could be `2700K` or `2800K`. This is my current query:

```
if ($lightColorCode === '2800K') {
    $correspondingLamps = Lamp::where(['fitting' => $fitting, 'dimmability' => $dimmable, 'light_color_code' => $lightColorCode])
        ->orWhere(['fitting' => $fitting, 'dimmability' => $dimmable, 'light_color_code' => '2700K'])
        ->get();
}
```

But it returns all the `Lamps` where `fitting` or `dimmability` or the `light_color_code` matches but they should all match. I don't see what is wrong with this query?

**Update:**
As in the comments suggested I looked at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping and I created the following query:

```
        $lamps = DB::table('lamps')
            ->where('fitting', '=', $fitting)
            ->where('dimmability', '=', $dimmable)
            ->where(function ($query, $lightColorCode) {
                $query->where('light_color_code', '=', $lightColorCode)
                    ->orWhere('light_color_code', '=', '2700K - 827 Zeer warm wit');
            })
            ->get();
```

But this returns:

> Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\CompareController::App\Http\Controllers{closure}(),
>   1 passed and exactly 2 expected

I guess this is because I pass `$lightColorCode` as parameter but I need that parameter in my `where`.

Comment: use parameter grouping, follow this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 4 Eloquent Query Using WHERE with OR AND OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-4-eloquent-query-using-where-with-or-and-or)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the necessary variables from the parent scope into the closure with the use keyword.

```
$correspondingLamps = Lamp::where(['fitting' => $fitting, 'dimmability' => $dimmable])->where(function($query) use ($lightColorCode){
            $query->where(['light_color_code' => $lightColorCode])->orWhere('light_color_code' => '2700K');})->get();
```

check this for details https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$correspondingLamps = Lamp::where(['fitting' => $fitting, 'dimmability' => $dimmable])
                    ->where(function($query) use ($lightColorCode){
                      $query->where(['light_color_code' => $lightColorCode]) // 2800K
                      ->orWhere('light_color_code' => '2700K');
                    })
                    ->get();
```