# Laravel Search Query which meets conditions

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have this code that is to search for records.

Admins are able to see all records, this is the query for admins

```
$trainings = Training::where('staffName', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
            ->orWhere('programTitle', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
            ->orWhere('trainer', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
            ->paginate();
```

Whereas Employees should only see their records, so how do I add this condition into the existing query for the search function? This is the query I have for the Employee search currently

```
$employees = Training::where('staffName',$username)
            ->orWhere('staffName', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
            ->orWhere('programTitle', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
            ->orWhere('trainer', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
            ->paginate();
```

I have another version for Managers, which is meant to also refer to their roles from a different table. I am trying it like this but it only is working properly when it comes to the Manager, but when the function fetches anything related to staff under them it fetches all records instead of specific records.

```
$managers = DB::table('trainings')
            ->join('users','users.id','=','trainings.staff_id')
            ->select('trainings.staffName','programTitle','trainer','trainingDate','hours')
            ->where('trainings.staffName',$username)
            ->orWhere('reportingTo',$username)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('trainings.staffName', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
                  ->orWhere('programTitle', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
                  ->orWhere('trainer', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%");
        })
        ->paginate();
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995102/laravel-eloquent-query-using-where-with-or-and-or

about the usage of grouping in models

Comment: which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: Did you setup a model relationship between training and employees? I think that would be the best way to go about it, so for the employee you would do Employee::with(['training' => fn($query) => $query->where....]) that should already be scoped to that employee. WIth Admins you'd get them like before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of orWhere is wrong because orWhere remove all conditions if it's true try this code below

```
Training::where('staffName', $username)
                ->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('staffName', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
                          ->orWhere('programTitle', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
                          ->orWhere('trainer', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%");
                })
                ->paginate();
```

For the last query

```
$managers = DB::table('trainings')
                      ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'trainings.staff_id')
                      ->select('trainings.staffName', 'programTitle', 'trainer', 'trainingDate', 'hours')
                      ->where(function ($query) use ($username) {
                          $query->where('trainings.staffName', $username)
                                ->orWhere('reportingTo', $username);
                      })
                      ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                          $query->where('trainings.staffName', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
                                ->orWhere('programTitle', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
                                ->orWhere('trainer', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%");
                      })
                      ->paginate();
```

Comment: This code functions properly. I have another case for a different role which is manager. I have been trying the code. I have added it into the question above, could you look at it and let me know if I can make any improvements?

Comment: I updated my answer to help with the last query

Comment: Hi @Wael Khalifa, I have another question do you by any chance know how to do it?

Comment: Hey @jypersona sure how can i help you

Comment: It is a sortable function that I am trying to work out. I posted another question. If you have time and are willing please check that one out. I would really appreciate that

Comment: let me know if you have an idea on that. Thanks

Comment: I will check it

Answer (score 0):

here's when [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) comes to the rescue.

```
class Training extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeFilterByRole($query, $roleId, $searchInput)
    {
        if ($roleId === 3) { 
            return $query->where('staffName', 'LIKE', "%{$searchInput}%")
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Then in your controller

```
Training::where('programTitle', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
        ->orWhere('trainer', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
        ->FilterByRole(3, $request->search)
        ->get();
```

Comment: I don't have something like roleID, what do I do in this case? I uploaded a full version of my code on another question could you check that one?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a global scope for that it will automatically apply in all existing queries:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(function (Builder $builder) {
        if (auth()->check() and auth()->user()->role == 3) {
            $builder->where('staffName', 'LIKE', "%{request()->get('search_name')}%")
        }
   });
}
```